# In Java, how do you enforce Stack.pop() as a parameter?

Tags: java, stack

I have two stacks.
I want to be able to push any element onto one, but only if it was popped off the other.

Instead of My current function looks like this:

```
public void pushValue(int poppedValue) {
  Stack.push(value)
}
```

I want the function to look something like this:

```
public void pushValue(pop() poppedValue) {
  Stack.push(value)
}
```

How could I set the `pop()` function as a parameter, instead of an int?
In other words, how can I set the parameter to only accept a value that was popped from somewhere?

Comment: Just pass the first Stack so that method can take care of poping the value and pushing it onto Stack two.

Comment: You could pass your method the stack itself and let it pop the value (though that may cause a few design problems), but there's no way to guarantee that an `int` will have a specific "history".

Comment: Do you mean that you want a single operation that pops a value off one stack and puts it onto the other?  Or do you want a stack that only accepts values that have, at some point in the past, been taken off of another stack?

Comment: @DaveCosta I want the function itself to pop the value off a stack and immediately use it. Something like `push(thing this function literally just popped)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way in Java to express that constraint.  (Or in any other language, AFAIK)

(IMO) the best you can do is to pass the second `Stack` as an argument to the first one and make the first one responsible for popping a value; e.g.

```
public class Stack { 
    ...
    public int transferValue(Stack source) {
        int res = source.pop();  // throws exception if source is empty
        this.push(value);
        return res;
    }
}
```

This leaves you with problems regarding `push`:

- Do you remove it entirely from the `Stack` API?  If so, how do the elements get onto the `source` stack?
- Do you split the Stack API into `Stack` and `StackWithoutPush`?  If yes, which is the super-class / super-interface?  Neither alternative is perfect.  Either way, the subclass violates the contract of the superclass in some sense.  (C.f. the problem of `List` versus `UnmodifiableList` APIs.)

Comment: I think this answers it. Would it be worth putting a constraint along the lines of "if there's nothing to pop from the parameter stack, abort" or does `pop()` inherently take care of that on its own?

Comment: The `pop()` method takes care of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax isn't possible, but you *could* make the second stack a member field and then `push` **iff** the value is present when you `peek` at the second stack (through the field).

```
private Stack otherStack = null; // <-- set this somehow (constructor?), or pass it.

public void pushValue(int newValue) {
  if (otherStack != null && otherStack.peek() == newValue) {
    Stack.push(newValue); // <-- please observe naming conventions (stack)
  }
}
```

**Then**, `pop()` the value. Basically, `peek`, `push` **and** then `pop`.

Comment: Not sure that makes sense. If the value was popped from "otherStack" already, it wouldn't still be on that stack, so you wouldn't see it when you peek.

Comment: @DaveCosta Correct, read my last sentence. The order of operations is `peek`, `push`, `pop` to do what OP wants... I think.

Comment: But - the method takes the popped value as a parameter.  How would you call it if you haven't already popped the value?

Comment: @DaveCosta Ah, bad variable name from OP... that's value to `push` onto the stack.